# Subsection destroys ToC in PDF

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

in my thesis I have an abstract, the toc and then the content. The content sections start again with 1. When I add a subsection at the content section, the toc of the PDF is destroyed and shows something like this:

```
Abstract
----> Inhalt
      ----> Einleitung
            ----> title
```

instead of

```
Abstract
Inhalt
Einleitung
title
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered,listof=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\section{Abstract}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{II Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{II Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\addtocounter{section}{1}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Einleitung}
% next line messes all up
\subsection{title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use an article class (here `scrartcl`) for a thesis! Use either a book or report one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get also a warning:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same
 identifier (name{section.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

Gives the section numbers of hyperref a unique representation by redefining also `\theHsection` when you change `\thesection`. E.g.

```
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\Roman{section}}
```