# Links in toc link to roman instead of arabic numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, counters

I have a LaTeX document where I first have the list of tables and figures etc. and then the normal chapters.
The lists are numbered with roman numbers, the chapters with arabic numbers.

The toc includes everything I wanted in it but I have the problem that the links in the toc do not work as I want them to. When I click on chapter 1 for example, it leads me to the first listing (I), 2 leads to II, 3 leads to III, you get it.
When I follow the link to chapter 6 (where no matching roman number is existent), I get to chapter 6.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered,listof=totocnumbered, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
...
\usepackage{hyperref}
...

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\rhead{VERZEICHNISSE}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures 
\pagebreak
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\listoftables
\pagebreak
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Listingverzeichnis}
\lstlistoflistings
\pagebreak

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1} 

\section{foo}

Lorem Ipsum

\section{bar}

Lorem Ipsum

\end{document}
```

I hope I included every important part.
I have pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) on MacOS installed and use VS Code with "LaTeX workshop".

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21192/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for your quick supply, this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

So, as Ulrike linked in the comment, this is fixed by adding \theHsection after every occurence of \thesection, e.g.:

```latex
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\arabic{section}}
```